# How to handle the exceptions occured in expressions used in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, exception

I am having an expression to divide a number and get the percentage and display it in vf page. The following expression in visualforce page working fine previously is now complaining and ended with an error displaying on the page as given in the screen shot.

Is there a way to handle this exception that is particularly happening in visualforce page expressions the same way as we did in apex code?

```
 <apex:param value="{!((sis.SalesCurrent-sis.SalesPrevious)/sis.SalesPrevious)*100}"/>
```

and the apex:column that contains the above code snippet is follows.

```
<apex:column headervalue="% Change" style="text-align:right;">
        <font color="{!IF(sis.SalesCurrent < sis.SalesPrevious, 'red', 'green')}">
            <apex:outputtext value="{0, number, 0}"> 
            <apex:param value="{!((sis.SalesCurrent-sis.SalesPrevious)/sis.SalesPrevious)*100}"/>
            </apex:outputtext>%
        </font>
     </apex:column>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the code below using [VisualForce Functions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm). This code will only display the correct result if `SalesCurrent` and `SalesPrevious` are set. If they are null then 0 will be displayed.

```
{! IF( 
      AND(
          ISBLANK(sis.SalesCurrent), 
          ISBLANK(sis.SalesPrevious) 
      ), 
      0,
      (((sis.SalesCurrent-sis.SalesPrevious)/sis.SalesPrevious)*100)
   )
}
```

An easier and cleaner option would be to do the calculation in the controller, including any null guards (and divide by zero errors), and then use that variable in the VF page

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle formula expression error by something like `try` `catch`. To make formula expression working you have to use perfect logic by considering the expected input.

For ex: consider if there is expression which should have number field then proceed otherwise don't in that case you can check the value is number or not as:

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!IF(ISNUMBER(number),'format','NOT A NUMBER')}"/>
```

or you can use like that:

```
<apex:outputpanel>
    <apex:outputtext rendered={!ISNUMBER(number)}" value="{0, number, 0}"/>
    <apex:outputtext rendered={!!ISNUMBER(number)}" value="Invalid value"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Basically, there are several ways to validate the input before proceeding which we can use to prevent unexpected errors.